# Opened a shapefile using geopandas, but shape doesn't overlap map in the background

Tags: python, data-visualization, gis, shapefile, geopandas

I have a shapefile on a train track going through the UK and want to plot it to see through where it is going

I have read this from the geopandas documentation and applied the same code:
https://geopandas.org/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html#sphx-glr-gallery-create-geopandas-from-pandas-py

```
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
#world = world.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3857'})

# We restrict to the UK
nation = world[world.name == 'United Kingdom']
ax = nation.plot(
    color='white', edgecolor='black', figsize=(10, 10), alpha=0)
#ctx.add_basemap(ax)

# We can now plot our ``GeoDataFrame``.
shp.plot(ax=ax, color='red')

plt.show()
```

shp is the .SHP shape file I've uploaded onto Python and gpd is short for geopandas

Unlike the example in the documentation, I can't see any borders and so have no sense of where the shape is

[image]

Some of the commented code is for adding a background to plots:

```
world = world.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3857'})
ctx.add_basemap(ax)
```

This produces an output like this:
[image]

Totally opposite problem - can see the borders but not the shape. Also in case you're thinking perhaps the problem is that the shape isn't on the UK, when I plot the whole world I still don't see the shape.

Comment: Try `ax = nation.plot(color='white', edgecolor='black', figsize=(10, 10), alpha=0.5)` and let me know if there is any difference. (different alpha value)

Comment: There is now a rough semi-transparent outline of the UK for the map with the epsg, but still no shape. For the one without the epsg there is no difference

Comment: Try removing alpha to get rid of transparency. Also, if you want just contours, did you try using `polyplot` instead of `plot`?

Answer (score 1):

Your `shp` has a different CRS than `world`. You can check that as `shp.crs` and `world.crs`. If you want to plot both at the same figure, you need to re-project one to the projection of the other.

```py
world = world.to_crs(shp.crs)
```